# Sending url as query parameter in rest webservice

Tags: java, rest, encryption, javax.crypto

I have written a rest service to encrypt and decrypt URL.

Encryption code:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/encrypt/")
public Response encryptWithQuery(@QueryParam("plainString") String plainString)
        throws JSONException {
    Response response = new Response();
    AesUtil util = new AesUtil(KEY_SIZE, ITERATION_COUNT);
    response = util.encrypt(SALT, IV, PASSPHRASE, plainString);
    return response;
}
```

Decryption code:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/decryptWP/")
public Response decryptWithQuery(@QueryParam("encryptString") String encryptString)
        throws JSONException {
    Response response = new Response();
    AesUtil util = new AesUtil(KEY_SIZE, ITERATION_COUNT);
    response = util.decrypt(SALT, IV, PASSPHRASE, encryptString);
    return response;
}
```

When i call my encrypt rest service i get the encrypted string

**url for encryption**

```
http://localhost:9080/kttafm/keybank/encrypt?plainString=http://localhost:9080/kttafm/master.jsp?abc=zyx
```

But when i call the decryption rest service i get below exception

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

But if i move from @Queryparam tp @path param,
The decryption works fine,

The decrypt method which works fine and decrypts the encrypted string is

```
 @GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/decrypt/{encryptString}")
public Response decrypt(@PathParam("encryptString") String encryptString)
        throws JSONException {
    Response response = new Response();
    AesUtil util = new AesUtil(KEY_SIZE, ITERATION_COUNT);
    response = util.decrypt(SALT, IV, PASSPHRASE, encryptString);
    return response;
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed info about the actual technology you're utilizing here? And please make clear which method moves form query to path.

Comment: By the way: Appending stuff to be encrypted to an url seems to be a bad idea from a security perspective.

Comment: @Queryparam could have encoding related processing. Can you show an example of an encrypted URL? did you debug to check that is matches exactly the input argument encryptString ?

Comment: Hello Guy, The encrypted string using @queryparam = "fbSjGsyDYfmJM4rAURhgdpX+XKQr8WTfiZC7PaBqK7KzfUEYau1cpXnhECqRT47n"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you always [encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) the parameter on client side, e.g. using [URLEncoder.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

For example, your URL for encryption must be

```
http://localhost:9080/kttafm/keybank/encrypt?plainString=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9080%2Fkttafm%2Fmaster.jsp%3Fabc%3Dzyx
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the encrypted string example: "fbSjGsyDYfmJM4rAURhgdpX+XKQr8WTfiZC7PaBqK7KzfUEYau1cpXnhECqRT47n", I can see that there is a "+" character which is candidate for URL decoding.
You may use this URL decoding website http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to see that the + sign is transformed when you decode your string.

This would cause errors in decryption as your algorithm will not have exactly what is expected.

You can make sure of that by adding some debug message in your decrypt method as in this example:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/decrypt/{encryptString}")
public Response decrypt(@PathParam("encryptString") String encryptString)
        throws JSONException {
    System.out.println(encryptString);
    Response response = new Response();
    ...
}
```

A solution would be to perform URL encoding on client side before calling the service.
In this case, your example would look like: "fbSjGsyDYfmJM4rAURhgdpX%2BXKQr8WTfiZC7PaBqK7KzfUEYau1cpXnhECqRT47n"

Note the conversion of the + sign.